# How to always have 50px white space above an Header (H2) element, even if the Header is not present?

Tags: html, css

I have a strange question. I always want 50px padding white space, above my Header(H2) Title. Where I am having trouble is that, if there is no Header, then the white space above the header is collapsing. Is there a way to always keep 50px padding above the Header, even if the header is not present?

I tried adding `padding-top: 50px` on my `myComponent` class. But that didn't work because, that is adding extra white space above, when there **is** a header present.

```html
<div class="myComponent">
 <div class="myContainer">
   <div id="head_Title" class="mainTitle">
    <h2 class="titleName"> This is a Title</h2>
   </div>
   <div id="description" class="mainDescription"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "when there is no header"? Is the `head_Title` div always there?

Comment: Why don't you simply set a padding-top of 50px for the header *parent* and set it to 0px for the header itself? And you might also want to set a min-height for the parent, in case it contains no child nor text

Comment: @clod9353 No the head_Title may not be there, but I want the space above the header to remain as it is, even if the header is not there.

Comment: @secan could please show an example of what you mean? It's kind of hard to follow.

Comment: Remove the margin from H2, and then add padding to MyComponent like you did.  Or don't remove the H2, but set it's contents to `&nbsp;`. Just noticed @secan says pretty much the same thing, but slow on mobile. :)

Comment: @Keith I don't have any H1 tags. Can you show a demo of what you mean?

Comment: @MylesEnist. Sorry I of course meant H2..

Comment: You tagged your question with *javascript* and *jquery*. Are you sure your issue has something to do with them?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it for all your document:

```html
<html>
<head>
...
<style>
h2 { padding-top: 0; }
#head_Title { padding-top: 50px; }
</style>
...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No this does not work because, there is already 50px padding above the h2(header). If I add padding-top:50px, then that is adding extra 50px whitespace that is already there.

Comment: I've edited my answer as I misunderstood what you needed.

Comment: So even if there is no header can I still have 50px space on top?

Comment: If there is no `h2` yes if there is no `<div id="head_Title">` no.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution depends on whether or not the DIV.mainTitle is really actually gone or just empty .. what works in either case is an additional wrapper around it, which has the desired padding-top.

```
<style>
h2{padding-top:0;}
.spacer{ padding-top: 50px; }
.myComponent{ background-color: #eee; }
.myContainer{ background-color: #ddd; }
.mainDescription{ min-height: 1em; background-color: #aaa; }
</style>


<div class="myComponent">
 <div class="myContainer">
   <div class="spacer"><div id="head_Title" class="mainTitle">
    <h2 class="titleName"> This is a Title</h2>
   </div></div>
   <div id="description" class="mainDescription"></div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="myComponent">
 <div class="myContainer">
   <div class="spacer"></div>
   <div id="description" class="mainDescription"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Of course the above code is broken due to doubled-IDs .. it's meant to be read as two examples of the HTML .. bottom one with DIV.mainTitle GONE.